# Tip for running Windows MATLAB scripts in Linux Python Code

Tags: python, linux, matlab, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I've used Windows to develop a MATLAB script, and wish to use it from within a Linux Python application.
As I've searched online, my options are:

1. Get a MATLAB license for Linux, compile the code to .sh file in the Linux host computer / container and run the MATLAB script from within the Python app as an os command (I should get both the MATLAB for Linux, also MCR for linux to be later on run by the Python app)
2. Get a MATLAB license for Linux, install the matlab.engine in the host computer / container, and run the MATLAB script (called help_please.m) as is using the following code:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.help_please(nargout=0)
```

(Here, I don't have to get the MCR)

Which option should work more efficiently? In general, which one do you recommend?
Is there any other way that works better which I haven't thought about already?

Thanks!

(As far as I know, there's no escape from getting a MATLAB license for Linux, as you cannot compile MATLAB in Windows to be executed in Linux).

Comment: How long does the MATLAB script run for? How often is it called in the same session?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Starting from 30 seconds and up to 10 minutes, depends on the input. It is called about 3-10 times (at its peak) every half an hour, depends on the time of day.

Comment: In that case, I think, the only differences between the two approaches is that with the compiler you can run your application on many machines, with only one license for MATLAB and the Compiler to initially build the executable; the other approach requires a license for each machine you run the MATLAB code on. If you run it on one machine only, I would go with the engine option, as that doesn’t require a separate license for the Compiler.

Comment: I don’t think you’ll notice any differences in performance. The engine option allows easier communication with the MATLAB script (transfer data to and from it). But you’ve already developed the script so you probably don’t need that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Plus, I guess the 1st solution is more useful in storage, since I am creating docker containers to contain the app, the 2nd solution would require MATLAB installed in each machine, compared to the 1st solution that makes use of the MCR only. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. The MCR is rather large as well though. But at least it doesn’t have to deal with all the license server issues.